# R/Shiny: How to detect overlapping circle markers?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet and Shiny with circle markers. Trying to figure out how to detect if a circle marker overlaps with one or more markers. I need to set the color of each marker based on whether they overlap or not. Have any of you done something like this before? Thankful for any suggestions :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mre] in your question!

Comment: I haven't written any code yet, this is a question to help in researching if this is possible at all. A minimal reproducible would just be a duplicate of https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html for example

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Not looking for code, just a little input on whether I have to manually calculate the distance between each circle in a map or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an accumulator. Represent the empty space as a n by m matrix of 0s, so each cell of the matrix represents a single point of the lowest granularity (like a pixel). Now mark the position of your marking in the accumulator with a 1. If you take the sum of the matrix at this point is should be 1. Now for all points that would be included in your circle mark with a 1 on the same accumulator. Now check the sum of the accumulator, if it is equal to the number of points in the circle + 1 the circle does not cover the point, but if is only equals the number of points the circle the marker is located within the circle.

Edit: If you want to look for overlaps: instead of just setting points to 1, increment the points by 1 for every object including it. So an over laps would have the value of 2 and a triple overlap would be a 3, etc. You could then find these by searching for local or global maximum or minimums.